# How to do method replacement using annotation in spring?

Tags: spring

I am learning spring i know using `<replaced-method .....>` tag we can replace the old implementation but i don't know how to do that using annotation. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

the configuration of Replace-Method is so long that the reason i can not share here but you can refer bellow link :-

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/MethodReplacementExample.htm

Comment: Mayank thank you, but this is xml configuration approach I am already familiar with this approach, I need to know is there any annotation spring provides for the same.

Comment: The question cleary indicates annotation, NOT xml.